# what are the assumptions for the drag force equation to work?

Tags: drag

We know that the force of drag $F_{d}=\frac{1}{2}\rho u^{2}C_{D}A$. I can't find a list of the assumptions for it to work. What are the assumptions for it to work?

Comment: Did you check the Wikipedia page for [the drag equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation)?

Comment: yes and???????????

Comment: And the second sentence gives you the assumptions that are used (which are what is provided in the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Drag equation describes the force of drag experienced by an object due to movement through a fully enclosing fluid. It is only accurate when the objects have a large enough Reynolds number(the ratio of momentum forces to viscous forces) to produce turbulence behind the object.